# create a athena table using "Create a table from datasource -> S3 Bucket Data" but giving 0 records

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I create a athena table using "Create a table from datasource -> S3 Bucket Data". This is how my query looked like when creating the table:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `category_april_data`(
  `marketplace` string, 
  `locale` string, 
  `batch_type` bigint, 
  `job_type` string, 
  `reported_at` string, 
  `snapshot_time` string, 
  `breakdown_type` string, 
  `breakdown_value` string, 
  `hero_score` double, 
  `bootstrap_hero_mean` double, 
  `bootstrap_lower_bound` double, 
  `bootstrap_upper_bound` double, 
  `bootstrap_std_deviation` double, 
  `asin_depth` bigint, 
  `sample_type` string, 
  `scoring_uri` string, 
  `snapshot_uri` string, 
  `labelling_uri` string, 
  `samples_path` string, 
  `head_queries` bigint, 
  `tail_queries` bigint, 
  `torso_queries` bigint, 
  `unclassified_queries` bigint, 
  `exact_percentage` double, 
  `substitute_percentage` double, 
  `complement_percentage` double, 
  `irrelevant_percentage` double, 
  `other` double, 
  `missing` double, 
  `total_asins` bigint)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  `partition_0` string, 
  `partition_1` string, 
  `partition_2` string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED 
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://mbr-metrics-prod/category_reruns_april'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1652614577')
```

Files in my category_reruns_april folder are stored like this
`s3://mbr-metrics-prod/category_reruns_april/{marketplace}/{locale}/{date}/file.csv`

Now when i am querying the data, it is not giving 0 records. What else needs to be done?
When i click on "load_partitons" for the table.
`` MSCK REPAIR TABLE `category_april_data`; `` this command gives

```
Partitions not in metastore:    category_april_data:AE/en_AE/2022-04-01 category_april_data:AE/en_AE/2022-04-02 ........
```

Comment: Did you try using Glue crawler to generate the table (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-running.html)? If you have any mistakes with the type of fields or columns, the query will not return any values. For example, if you have a header in the files they will confuse the engine and workers.

Comment: For partitions, path should look something like this: s3://mbr-metrics-prod/category_reruns_april/partition_0={marketplace}/partition_1={locale}/partition_2={date}/file.csv